# PDO beginTransaction Not Letting Script Execute

Tags: php, pdo, transactions

I have a PHP script using PDO Transactions.

```
$PDO->beginTransaction();

$sth = $PDO->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_last_packing_upload (folderID, subfolderID) VALUES (1, 1)");
$sth->execute();
```

For some reason, this works locally (the `INSERT` runs), but not when I push it to my remote server.

To get my `INSERT` to work remotely, I need to put it ABOVE the `$PDO->beginTransaction();` line. The following works remotely:

```
$sth = $PDO->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_last_packing_upload (folderID, subfolderID) VALUES (1, 1)");
$sth->execute();

$PDO->beginTransaction();
```

Why does my `INSERT` not fire on my remote server when I have it placed inside the `beginTransaction`? I have many other PHP scripts on the same remote server using transactions and they all work fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have another script which has already opened an uncommitted transaction on the server? Do you have PDO throwing useful errors? `$PDO->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I checked MySQL using `show innodb status;` and I don't see any open or hanging transactions. I do have that line you mentioned: `$PDO->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );` but where will those errors actually be sent so I can view them?

Comment: If this is in a `try/catch` presumably you're catching the exception somewhere? If it isn't in a try/catch, the exception will be fatal and you can see it on screen if you have display_errors turned on -`ini_set('display_errors', 1);` Otherwise, go check your web server's error log to see the details of the fatal error, assuming you have `error_reporting = E_ALL` in php.ini or `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski thank you! I do have my script wrapped in a `try/catch` and in the catch, I'm attempting to write out the error in a file on my remote server... However, for whatever reason, it is NOT writing to that remote file. I ran the same script locally to test, and it did write to the file on my local machine. Is there a setting in `php.ini` that may be blocking my write attempts to the file on my server?

Comment: If you are catching the exception, you would be prevented from writing the file if the web server doesn't have write access to the location you're trying to write to.  Assuming you have _some_ access to the web server's error log, I would do `error_log($e->getMessage())` to send it to the error log, assuming `$e` is the caught exception.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski thanks! I got my error logging working correctly and I see the problem.. it's completely unrelated to the transaction. I would like to give you credit, because your help did lead me to the solution here. Would you mind putting an answer in so that I can accept it? Thanks again Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless there is an existing open transaction (`$PDO->beginTransaction()` was previously called but uncommitted), there should be no issue with the code as posted.  If there was an open transaction, PDO would throw an exception when attempting to start a new one.

You already have PDO setup to throw exceptions rather than error silently with

```
$PDO->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

and if your transaction and `INSERT` statement code are wrapped in a `try/catch` block, you will need to debug and inspect the error caught in the `catch` block.

An error caught in `catch (PDOException $e) {...}` won't go into PHP's built-in error reporting mechanism on its own, so you'll need to force it to print to a location you can read. On a production web server, you won't want to print it to the screen, so instead I would recommend writing it to the web server's error log with PHP's [`error_log()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php). A simple write to the default log location requires only the message as a parameter.

```
try {
  // everything posted above
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  // Caught an error, write it to the log
  error_log("Error at line " . __LINE__ . " in " . __FILE__ . ": " . $e->getMessage());
  // Whatever else you already do to handle the error...
  // etc...
}
```

Comment: One question: In your last paragraph you say "An error caught in `catch...` won't go into PHP's built-in error reporting mechanism on its own". However, I removed my `error_log` call in the `catch` block and PHP still logged the error as if I had the call in there. Is there a reason for that? Just trying to understand...

Comment: @FastTrack Are you using a framework of some kind which may have defined its own error handling?  If PDO is throwing exceptions (rather than issuing E_WARNING) and  you catch those exceptions, they won't get logged as errors. But if PDO is actually issuing warnings rather than throwing exceptions, they may get logged.